# Como retornar lista dinâmica?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Como retornar uma `List<dynamic>` em ASP.NET MVC 5 e EntityFramework 6

Por exemplo eu tenho uma um Objeto com nome Usuario e mapeado no meu EDMX, quando eu faço para trazer os dados de forma dinâmica tipo fazer umas consulta avançada sem retornar um objeto do tipo Usuario.

Obs: isso é uma View o vwCaixa

```
select top 5 SUM(vrLancamento),nmTipoDocumento from vwCaixa group by nmTipoDocumento
```

Fiz assim:

```
public IList<dynamic> resumoCaixa()
        {
            IList<dynamic> lista = new List<dynamic>();

            TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);



            using (var ctx = new dbProClinicEntities())
            {
               var t = ctx.vwCaixa.GroupBy(g => new { documento = g.nmTipoDocumento, pago = g.dtPago, valor = g.vrLancamento })
               .Select(x => new { pago = x.Key.pago, tipoDocumento = x.Key.documento, vrLancamento = x.Sum(f => f.vrLancamento) })
               .Take(5).ToList();

                foreach(var f in t)
                {
                    lista.Add(f);
                }
            }

            return lista.ToList();
        }
```

No Controller estou retornando uma ViewBag:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AdminDAO dao = new AdminDAO();
        ViewBag.Caixa caixa = dao.resumoCaixa();
        return View();
    }
```

Na View estou fazendo assim:

```
<table class="table list">
                <tbody>
                    @foreach(var caixa in ViewBag.Caixa)
                    { 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#"><p class="title">@caixa.vrLancamento</p></a>
                            <p class="info">@caixa.tipoDocumento</p>
                        </td>
                   </tr>
                        }
                </tbody>
</table>
```

Mas dá o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está com algum problema? EM tese um `return new List<dynamic>();` deveria funcionar.

Comment: Por exemplo eu tenho uma um Objeto com nome Usuario e mapeado no meu EDMX, quando eu faço para trazer os dados de forma dinâmica tipo fazer umas consulta avançada sem retornar um objeto do tipo Usuario

Comment: Já melhorou mas ainda não entendi o que você quer. De qualquer forma edite a pergunta e coloque todos os detalhes possíveis. Com o que você colocou inicialmente não daria nem para adivinhar o que você realmente quer.

Comment: Vou colocar meu código para você analisar minuto.

Comment: Você deve [edit] a sua pergunta e não responder ela.

Comment: E prefira colar tudo como texto ao invés de imagem.

Comment: Desculpe sou novo no fórum, mais e ai deu uma olhada no meu código? lembrando que é uma View.

Comment: Ok amigo! blz...

Comment: Estou vendo aqui que o foco é mais postar uma coisa padronizada do que resolver problemas.

Comment: Lembrando que é uma view mapeada

Comment: Não entendi sua colocação poderia me mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: para casos assim, usa-se o padrão MVVM, com ViewModel

Answer (score 2):

No seu exemplo você não está passando a lista como model e sim pela view bag.
Também não é permitido passar uma classe anônima como model para a view. Crie uma view model e use na consulta linq.
Ex.:

```
var t = ctx.vwCaixa.GroupBy(g => new { documento = g.nmTipoDocumento, pago = g.dtPago, valor = g.vrLancamento }).Select(x => new **MINHAVIEWMODEL** { pago = x.Key.pago, tipoDocumento = x.Key.documento, vrLancamento = x.Sum(f => f.vrLancamento) }).Take(5).ToList();
```

e passe a variável `t` como model usando `return View(t);`

obs.: não esqueça de colocar na primeira linha da view `@model IEnumerable<MINHAVIEWMODEL>`